# Time zone in MathOverflow public dumps?

Tags: support, data-dump

Please forgive me if this is the wrong place to ask this question; I wasn't sure where it would be appropriate.

I grabbed a public dump of MathOverflow from [here](http://dumps.mathoverflow.net/).  I'm interested in analyzing the time stamps but unfortunately the time zone is not specified.  What is it?

Comment: I think likely it is UTC, as the other timings in MO. -- At least everything else would seem somewhat strange ... .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All dates and times should be in UTC. That's true on the site itself as well, with the occasional exception of chat (and even there, it's UTC internally).